# resize and pad numpy array with additional dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an np array with shape `(100,28,28)`

I would like to turn it to `(100,32,32,3)`

by padding with zero's and adding dimensions

I tried np.newaxis which got me as far as `(100,28,28,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough information about how you want the padding to be done, so I'll suppose an image processing setup:

1. Padding on both edges of the array
2. Array must be replicated along the newly added dimension

**Setup**

```py
import numpy as np

N, H, W, C = 100, 28, 28, 3
x = np.ones((N, H, W))
```

**1. Padding**

```py
# (before, after)
padN = (0, 0)
padH = (2, 2)
padW = (2, 2)

x_pad = np.pad(x, (padN, padH, padW))

assert x_pad.shape == (N + sum(padN), H + sum(padH), W + sum(padW))
```

**2. Replicate along a new dimensions**

```py
x_newd = np.repeat(x_pad[..., None], repeats=C, axis=-1)

assert x_newd.shape == (*x_pad.shape, C)
assert np.all(x_newd[..., 0] == x_newd[..., 1])
assert np.all(x_newd[..., 1] == x_newd[..., 2])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `resize` function on your array. This is the code I tried.

```
arr = np.ones((100,28,28))
arr.resize((100, 32, 32, 3))
print(arr)
```

The newly added items are all 0s.